# Андроид Студио. Вывод текста из файла в соответствии с текущей датой

Tags: java, listview, android-textview, android-xml

Подскажите, как лучше реализовать в Андроид студио вывод текста в соответствии с текущей датой из файла с разным текстом каждый день, например, ежедневника, органайзера или типа того.

Comment: Можно пару примеров? И почему именно в "Андроид студио", может в целом на Java?

Comment: я делаю приложение в андроид студио и в одном из активити нужно реализовать вывод текста, типа гороскопа на текущий день. Но в общем, можно и на java